# C++ error: expected primary-expression before 'int'?

Tags: c++

update: 
so I was able to compile and run the program and it seems to work! However, the variable for judge score value 2.3 - stores in an odd fashion and is throwing off the calculation. when i enter 2.3, the store value is 2.299999999998 - why is this? The calcScore or lowest and highest functions may be at error because the final score is off by 0.3 when entering scores, 2.3 - 5.5 - 5.5 - 5.5 - 8.5 - Any ideas?

```
// file name starSearch.cpp
// author: SK
// last modified: 03/19/2012

#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void getJudgeData(double &);
void calcScore(double, double, double, double, double);
int findLowest(double, double, double, double, double);
int findHighest(double, double, double, double, double);

//declare variables
double score1;
double score2;
double score3;
double score4;
double score5;

int main()
{
    getJudgeData(score1); //Call getJudgeData for first judge score
    getJudgeData(score2); //Call getJudgeData for second judge score
    getJudgeData(score3); //Call getJudgeData for third judge score 
    getJudgeData(score4); //Call getJudgeData for fourth judge score
    getJudgeData(score5); //Call getJudgeData for fifth judge score
    calcScore(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5);    //calculate contestant score
    return 0; 
}

//
//Begin function prototypes definitions
//

//defines calcScore.
void calcScore(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    double total = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - findLowest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5) - findHighest(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)) / 3;
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << "The contestant's final score is: " << total << endl;
}

//defines getJudgeData. this function asks each judge for their score.
void getJudgeData(double &score)
{
    cout << "Judge, enter the contestant's score: ";
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 0 || score > 10) //validate score between 0-10, else display error msg
    {
    cout << "ERROR: Enter a value in the range 0-10.\n";
    return getJudgeData(score);
    }
    return;
}

//defines findLowest. this function returns the lowest score entered.
int findLowest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    if (score1 < score2 && score1 < score3 && score1 < score4 && score1 < score5)
    {
        return score1;
    }

    else if (score2 < score1 && score2 < score3 && score2 < score4 && score2 < score5)
    {   
        return score2;
    }

    else if (score3 < score1 && score3 < score2 && score3 < score4 && score3 < score5)
    {
        return score3;
    }

    else if (score4 < score1 && score4 < score2 && score4 < score3 && score4 < score5)
    {
        return score4;
    }

    else if (score5 < score1 && score5 < score2 && score5 < score3 && score5 < score4)
    {
        return score5;
    }
}

//defines findHighest. this functio returns the highest score entered.
int findHighest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3 && score1 > score4 && score1 > score5)
    {
        return score1;
    }

    else if (score2 > score1 && score2 > score3 && score3 > score4 && score3 > score5)
    {   
        return score2;
    }

    else if (score3 > score1 && score3 > score2 && score3 > score4 && score3 > score5)
    {
        return score3;
    }

    else if (score4 > score1 && score4 > score2 && score4 > score3 && score4 > score5)
    {
        return score4;
    }

    else if (score5 > score1 && score5 > score2 && score5 > score3 && score5 > score4)
    {
        return score5;
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL:

I am getting the compiler error on line 39 where my algebra expression is written with the integer 3. I just cant figure out how to average the five scores and remove the lowest and highest. the functions to determine which is highest and lowest seem to be in order though.. Please help.

Thank you.

```
*// file name starSearch.cpp
// author: SK
// last modified: 03/19/2012

#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

//function prototypes
void getJudgeData(double);
void calcScore();
int findLowest();
int findHighest();

//declare variables
double score1;
double score2;
double score3;
double score4;
double score5;

int main()
{
    getJudgeData(score1); //Call getJudgeData for first judge score
    getJudgeData(score2); //Call getJudgeData for second judge score
    getJudgeData(score3); //Call getJudgeData for third judge score 
    getJudgeData(score4); //Call getJudgeData for fourth judge score
    getJudgeData(score5); //Call getJudgeData for fifth judge score
    calcScore();    //calculate contestant score
    return 0; 
}

//
//Begin funtion prototypes definitions
//

//defines calcScore.
void calcScore(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    double total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - int findLowest(a, b, c, d, e) - intfindHighest(a, b, c, d, e) / 3;
    cout << "The contestant's final score is: " << total << endl;
}

//defines getJudgeData. this function asks each judge for their score.
void getJudgeData(double score)
{
    cout << "Judge, enter the contestant's score: ";
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 0 || score > 10) //validate score between 0-10, else display error msg
    {
    cout << "ERROR: Enter a value in the range 0-10: ";
    cin >> score;
    }
    else
    return;
}

//defines findLowest. this function returns the lowest score entered.
int findLowest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    if (score1 < score2, score3, score4, score5)
    {
        return score1;
    }

    else if (score2 < score1, score3, score4, score5)
    {   
        return score2;
    }

    else if (score3 < score1, score2, score4, score5)
    {
        return score3;
    }

    else if (score4 < score1, score2, score3, score5)
    {
        return score4;
    }

    else if (score5 < score1, score2, score3, score4)
    {
        return score5;
    }
}

//defines findHighest. this functio returns the highest score entered.
int findHighest(double score1, double score2, double score3, double score4, double score5)
{
    if (score1 > score2, score3, score4, score5)
    {
        return score1;
    }

    else if (score2 > score1, score3, score4, score5)
    {   
        return score2;
    }

    else if (score3 > score1, score2, score4, score5)
    {
        return score3;
    }

    else if (score4 > score1, score2, score3, score5)
    {
        return score4;
    }

    else if (score5 > score1, score2, score3, score4)
    {
        return score5;
    }
}*
```

Comment: Why do you have `int findLowest(...)` in the middle of the expression?

Comment: not answer related but maybe you would want to replace `}*` at the end with `}`

Comment: that was caused by the site i believe, and is not in my actual code. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The functions are called `findLowest` and `findHighest` respectively. The `int` is their return type and should not be specified when calling them.

If this is causing you confusion, I'd suggest you find a good beginner-level C++ book and read up on function declaration and calling.

Comment: Yes agreed, I can recommend "Accelerated C++"

Comment: I incorrectly specified the function call statement.. i need to practice more.

Comment: @user1278971: especially since "`if (score1 < score2, score3, score4, score5)`" won't do what you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your previous answers, your `getJudgeData` function is very broken. It needs to take a double *reference*, else you will never modify the original variable and the function is worthless. In addition, you have no protection against a Judge entering a bad score *twice*.

```
void getJudgeData(double& score)
{
    cout << "Judge, enter the contestant's score: ";
    cin >> score;
    if (score < 0 || score > 10) //validate score between 0-10, else display error msg
    {
        cout << "ERROR: Enter a value in the range 0-10: ";
        return getJudgeData(score);
    }
    return;
}
```

This simple recursion will protect you from a judge entering bad data every time, and it also will correctly modify the original variable as your code seems to be written expecting it would.

Comment: I see. This is my first attempt at the functions..but i see how the if statement needs to be defined this way to return the the function

Comment: @user1278971: it doesn't return the function, it returns the _result_ of the function call.

Comment: @MooingDuck: What result? The function is `void`.

Comment: even though the function is void the variable "score" is being passed into the int main function for the function call variable score1, score2, ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your line:

`double total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - int findLowest(a, b, c, d, e) - intfindHighest(a, b, c, d, e) / 3;`

you shouldn't include the `int` identifier inline.  the complier already knows that your function returns an int.  instead write

`double total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - findLowest(a, b, c, d, e) - findHighest(a, b, c, d, e) / 3;`

As someone else pointed out, you might want to cast that to a double.  in which case, you would do that like this.

`double total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - (double)findLowest(a, b, c, d, e) - (double)findHighest(a, b, c, d, e) / 3;`

Still, this won't actually calculate the average, so you should use parenthesis to enforce order or operations.

`double total = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - (double)findLowest(a, b, c, d, e) - (double)findHighest(a, b, c, d, e)) / 3;`

Comment: how about the order of operations in c++ here? will that division not average the whole of the scores once subtracted?\

Comment: @user1278971  actually you are correct.  I will edit my answer

Comment: ok thank you. im finding it difficult to write the formulate..its definitely throwing me off with the inclusion of the function call statements.

Comment: @user1278971: If code is confusing because of too many things on a line, _please_ split it onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer provided by Chowlett, you will also want to reconsider your use of the comma operator within findLowest and findHighest.

For example, your line in findHighest

```
if (score1 > score2, score3, score4, score5)
```

is essentially exactly the same as

```
if (score5)
```

which is not what you seem to intend.

Comment: I am not sure how the i can compare the highest value of the five input scores. "if (score5)" will only compare one of the scores it seems.

Comment: @user1278971 - There's no shortcutting, I'm afraid; you need `if (score1 > score2 && score1 > score3 && ... && score1 > score5)` if you want to do the comparison that way.

Comment: I see.. Well the comparisons with the and representation will do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to perform a cast there? That is done with parentheses (double) , and I would assume double is what you would want to cast too, although I am not sure if it is needed there.

Comment: does not need to cast, this is an implicit conversion, but he may have wanted to.

Comment: im not sure if this is actually needed in the function definition.

Comment: not the function definitions but the expression `double total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 - (double)findLowest(a, b, c, d, e) - (double)findHighest(a, b, c, d, e) / 3` as pointed out by Sam